# How to calculate sum of square of log series

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

I have an algorithm, and I have figured out that its run-time complexity follows the following formula:

```
[log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2
```

The base of log is 2.

How do I figure out what the Θ/Ο algorithmic complexity is from this formula?

Comment: This might get better attention over on the math stack exchange.

Comment: @slugonamission: Does math.SE deal with algorithms?

Comment: Are those square brackets supposed to indicate some kind of nearest integer value operation?

Comment: recursion. Tail recursion is probably the safest bet for you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - that...shouldn't have been a comment, instead a report. And I'd have thought it would be more fitting over there, especially as it's starting to get into shorthand calculation of equations rather than an algorithm in a way.

Comment: I see, you have calculated the complexity of an algorithm to be this sum, and you want to know what order of complexity this actually represents.

Comment: you can put the series in an actual for loop in python, use the math.log(number, base) function to calculate the log and pow(num,power) to raise the term to the appropriate power. Take a look at this link http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

Comment: Hint: You can compute the order of complexity by estimating the Σ by calculating the ∫ instead.

Comment: @jxh thanks! Actually I found this page http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=627139, but it seems useless for me to do the calculation :(

Comment: In this case, you can almost tell by looking the bound is n times your highest order term. I expect the integral will confirm that.

Comment: @Pratik Thanks Pratik, but since n is unspecific number, even though I assign a large number to it, in the final I still cannot get a appropriate form of n.

Comment: Based on a continuum approximation (sum `->` integral), it looks like the asymptotic complexity is `O(n (log(n))^2)`. Source: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B%28ln%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%5D)

Comment: The complexity is `Θ(n(log(n))^2)`.  Just look at the last half (from `n/2` to `n`) of the sum: `n/2` terms between `(log(n/2))^2=(log(n)-1)^2` and `(log(n))^2`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you! I guess it is like this, but should we use Big-O rather than Theta by your way?

Comment: Theta is, by definition, the same as Big-O and Big-Omega at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the upper bound you can reason similat to log(n!) = O(nlog(n))

```
[log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2 < [log(n)]^2 + ... + [log(n)]^2
                                                            = n[log(n)]^2

[log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2  = O( n[log(n)]^2 )
```

To prove for lower bound, need to show that given sum is >= constant multiple of n[log(n)]^2

Deleting first half of the terms from the sum

```
[log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2 >= [log(n/2)]^2 + [log(n/2 + 1)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2
```

Replacing each term with log(n/2) ^ 2

```
[log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2  >= (n/2) * [log(n/2)]^2
```

Lower bound = `(n/2) * [log(n) - 1] ^ 2`

We can prove that `log(n) - 1 >= (1/2) * log(n)`

Hence lower bound = `(n/8) * [log(n)] ^ 2` and Upper bound =  `n * [log(n)] ^ 2`

So  `Θ([log(1)]^2 + [log(2)]^2 + [log(3)]^2 + ....... + [log(n)]^2) = n * [log(n)] ^ 2`